# %rowtype in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, rowtype

Is there anything equivalent to postgres/oracle %rowtype in MYSQL???. I want to select all columns and store it in %rowtype in mysql because my table columns count increases/decreases dynamically.Is there anything workaround for this?? please help me out friends.

```
SELECT * INTO var1 FROM table1;
```

Comment: There is no such data type in mysql as rowtype. You need to fetch fields into separate variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Shadow

Answer (score 0):

Old question but might help someone searching. MariaDB has this feature as of version 10.3 by setting sql_mode=ORACLE. See [docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql_modeoracle/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).